# How can I get a list of table names from an existing sqlite database using SQLite.NET?

Tags: c#, sqlite

Using the [sqlite.net nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net/), how I can I get a list of tables from the database using an instance of SQLiteConnection? I need this functionality so I can detect when my database schema has changed and the database requires a rebuild.

For example, I've defined the entities:

```
public class Body
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int PrimaryKey { get; set; }
}

public class Foot
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int PrimaryKey { get; set; }
}

public class Leg
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int PrimaryKey { get; set; }

}
```

I need to retrieve the tables in a list of strings that would contain: `Body, Leg, Foot`.

The SQLiteConnection class has the `TableMappings` property that can perform this behaviour. It can only be used after calling `SQLiteConnection.CreateTable`; this is incorrect as calling `CreateTable` generates the table binding for an object AND executes the `create table if not exists` command, thus changing the schema.

The query `"SELECT NAME from sqlite_master"` can do this (I've tested it in a database browser) but I can't execute it using `Execute`, `ExecuteScalar` or `Query`. How can I retrieve a list of the tables in a database using this command?

Comment: small correction - the TableMappings property is populated when any Type is passed to the connection. So calling connection.Get<T> will add an entry for T in the TableMappings. It's just a cache - sort of misleading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following extension method provides the ability to query the tables inside an existing database without using the ORM layer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SQLite;

namespace MyApplication
{
    public static class SqliteExtensions
    {
        public static List<string> Tables (this SQLiteConnection connection)
        {
            const string GET_TABLES_QUERY = "SELECT NAME from sqlite_master";

            List<string> tables = new List<string> ();

            var statement = SQLite3.Prepare2 (connection.Handle, GET_TABLES_QUERY);

            try {
                bool done = false;
                while (!done) {
                    SQLite3.Result result = SQLite3.Step (statement);

                    if (result == SQLite3.Result.Row) {

                        var tableName = SQLite3.ColumnString (statement, 0);

                        tables.Add(tableName);
                    } else if (result == SQLite3.Result.Done) {
                        done = true;
                    } else {
                        throw SQLiteException.New (result, SQLite3.GetErrmsg (connection.Handle));
                    }
                }
            }
            finally {   
                SQLite3.Finalize (statement);
            }

            return tables;
        }
    }
}
```